# globally distributed SharePoint 2016 architecture

Tags: azure, sharepoint

currently, we have a SharePoint 2016 site in Azure US region and wanna expand its services to Azure Europe, Southeast Asia, and Australia. Azure Traffic Manager should be able to do traffic distribution according to latency. But I do not know how to sync data between all these sites. Azure network latency between these regions should be around 150ms with quite good bandwidth but no guarantee.

I am not familiar with SharePoint 2016, just want to check if anyone has implemented such global distributed SharePoint 2016 sites. Is it possible to just build use SQL DB synchronization function for data synchronization between different sites?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if you are talking about SharePoint Online or running the "on premises" version of SharePoint in Azure.

For the former, Microsoft has recently announced multi-geopgraphy support for their SharePoint Online product: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/094e86f2-9ff0-40ac-af31-28fcaba00c1d

For the "on premises" version you cannot use native SQL capabilities to create synchronized copies of SharePoint content databases let alone copies of all the system SharePoint databases.  If you are attempting to have a single SharePoint site that is editable by SharePoint servers and databases in different parts of the world you need to strongly consider that you are doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your answer, I am asking about the "on premises" way. our direction is to build 4 content-synchronized SharePoint sites in US, East Asia, Europe and Australia, all the sites support uploading and downloading. It allows 1 hour delay for synchronization between sites. I realized that only sync DB is not the correct direction to do it. I guess we need to write some automation scripts or even message queue to sync contents manually.